# How would a three dimensional standing wave created inside a box look like?

Tags: thermal-radiation

While deriving Rayleigh-Jeans law, in order to make a standing inside a cube, a condition is put forward which says electric field must vanish when the EM wave hits a surface of the cube.

I want to know, when an EM wave hits a certain point on a surface inside the cube, does it come back straight through the way it fell and keep traveling the same distance back and forth and so creates a standing wave? Or it gets reflected in another direction and keeps roaming the box and the mathematics is developed in a certain way so that electric field vanishes every time the EM wave hits a certain surface of the cube and is sustained every time as a consequence?

Answer (score 0):

First it depends in what direction it reaches the wall, it is reflected according to the law of reflection. aA standing wave can only develop if it hit perpendicular and the wavelength  distance to the opposing wall ist a multiple of $\lambda/2$

Comment: Can you please explain what the mathematics of Rayleigh Jeans law says in case of standing waves inside the cube?

Comment: Maybe just see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL1GrzXhbwA